# Entering a character results in infinite loop

Tags: c

When I try to enter a character (letters in particular), the code results in an infinite loop. May I know why is that and are there any remedies without adding any new libraries?

PS. I've only been coding for a month or so.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
int n;

    do {
        printf("Enter N: ");
        scanf("%d", &n);
    } while (n != 0);

}
```

Comment: You aren't checking the return code from scanf

Comment: Can you please expound, do you mean that I should add in if statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `scanf` fails to parse the input, it will leave it in the input buffer. The next iteration `scanf` will read the exact same input and again fail.

A common way to handle invalid input is to read a whole line into a buffer using e.g. [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) and then attempt to parse it using `sscanf`, remembering to check what it [*returns*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf#Return_value).